# Removendo Carácter específico php/mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, query

Como remover carácter específico * (ASTERISCOS) de um campo do banco de dados?
Existe uma coluna no banco que possui informações e no início e no fim de cada palavra possui vários **asteriscos** esses por sua vez são usados para inserir como **NEGRITO** ao ser enviado uma mensagem para whatsapp. Mas também preciso mostrar o conteúdo dessa coluna em uma tabela html porém quero remover esses *

Já tentei com SUBSTRING mas não deu certo pois o conteúdo não é padrão e hora funciona, hora a consulta não é eficaz.

Por ex:
Ex:01

Esse * texto * é uma frase de * teste *

Ex:02
Hoje o * faturamento * foi * menor *

Sendo assim a consulta usando SUBSTRING não é eficaz pois as posições pode mudar.

Alguém poderia me mostrar uma solução pra esse caso?
Lembrando que os caracteres que preciso remover são todos os * que por ventura possa aparecer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$teste = "Olá * mundo * mais * bonito";
$replace = str_replace("*", "9", $teste);
echo $replace;
```

Explicação: O str_replace() irá substituir todas as ocorrências do caracter que você quer em uma string. Você poderia usar outra função do php para trocar somente um determinado número de carácter, porém, percebo que você não quer isso.

Outra forma de fazer que irá lhe ajudar muito é usando o RegExp(Expressão Regular). Peço que estude sobre ela, pois existem vários casos que só ela irá ajudar de uma forma ideal.

Comment: Legal  aguardo sim

Comment: Se minha resposta não foi o que você queria, pode me falar que tentarei lhe ajudar. Aguardo um retorno seu para saber se consegui lhe ajudar.

Comment: Muito obrigado Jeferson. Deus te abençoe.

Comment: Amém. Você também. Se tiver mais alguma dúlvida, pode falar.